How to fix missing C++ symbol at link time such as ` undefined reference to `_ZTV8Settings'`
The linker says:
.pio/build/nano/src/canbus.cpp.o:(.literal._ZN7DalyBmsC5E6String[_ZN7DalyBmsC5E6String]+0x4): undefined reference to `_ZTV8Settings'

To me it complains a global settings referenced from canbus.cpp source file is not defined anywhere.
The map file shows additional references to it as follows:
_ZTV8Settings                                     .pio/build/nano/src/inverterModeDetector.cpp.o
                                                  .pio/build/nano/src/dalyBms.cpp.o
                                                  .pio/build/nano/src/canbus.cpp.o

Using objdump -tC, I see the referenced object is the Settings vtable (the mangled _ZTV8Settings being Settings):
00000000         *UND*  00000000 vtable for Settings
00000000         *UND*  00000000 vtable for DalyBmsSettings
00000000         *UND*  00000000 DalyBms::_defaultCapacityScale

So I tried to create a useless global as follows:
#include "settings.h"

/// Settings vtable: For some reasons I don't have time to spot, the Settings vtable isn't defined
/// so I set up a global to force it create the vtable.
Settings settings;

But this didn't make it though.
I must add that instances of Settings are part of others classes.
What should I do to fix the issue I have with the linker?
The Settings class for reference:

/// @brief  The abstract Settings struct
struct Settings {
    /// Saves to persistance
    virtual void saveToPersistance();
    /// Loads from persistance
    virtual void loadFromPersistance();

    /// Marshall all values to make sure we are in range
    virtual void _marshallValues();

    /// @brief Update settings from the [args] and store to the persistance storage.
    /// Note that the order of the arguments is of great importance, shuffling them 
    /// results in unexpected behaviour.
    /// @param args The list of settings
    /// @param size The number of settings
    virtual void storeSettings(float args[], size_t size);

    /// @brief Dump data
    /// @param message The message to display in the dump header
    virtual void dump(const char * message);


    /// @brief Load settings from the persistan storage
    inline void loadSettings() {
        // Load settings
        loadFromPersistance();
    }

    /// @brief Sends the config as a Json SDLTP thru BLE
    virtual void bleSendJson();
};


Linker should print something more something in demangled version. It should show you vtable for Settings - this is demangled version of _ZTV8Settings (I've used this site). Basically looks like you do not build/link translation unit which would cause synthesis of vtable. Problem most probably is hiden in a build process.

Thanks for the Web site. I used objdump -C to see the unmangled name.

You should have virtual destructor and make sure all virtual functions have a definitions, not just declarations.

Are you asking how to fix the probem with missing symbols, or asking in general how to find symbols in compiled objects and libraries? Missing vtable to XXX usually means that not all of the virtual methods are defined. I see a couple of candidates in your struct Settings, possibly also missing virtual destructor.

Oh you're right. I edited the title to be more specific now.

Can you show us your settings.cpp? For sure some definitions are missing. Or source is OK, but you forgot to link your app to settings compiled object.

Offtopic: what is the purpose of having here virtual member functions in shown code? There is no any kind of inheritance shown and instance of Settings is used directly, so basically no reason to have polymorphic calls.

Settings is a root service for settings purpose in a RT firmware offered to many others services that need to persistant and communicate informations to others. Of course, in the provided code, I simply show you the Settings base class not to bother with the rest of the fw complexity.

The vtable for a class will usually be created in the compilation unit that defines the first non-inline method in the class.  In this case it will be the compilation unit (.cpp file) that defines Settings::saveToPersistance.  If you don't define that function anywhere, then it will appear as an undefined vtable for Settings

OK. XXX::saveToPersistance is defined in many Settings-inherited classes. Do you mean I must define it once for each inherited class?

It is not declared as pure (= 0) or inline in the header, so it must be defined somewhere in some compilation unit.  If not, you get undefined behavior (generally manifesting as a linker error like this)

I should have declared them pure then. I'll add this oil my TODOs for a yet-t-come  refactor

@StéphanedeLuca • You'll need a non-inline virtual ~Settings(); and have that defined once in an appropriate .cpp file.

Following advices from @Marek R and @pptazni, I've provided empty stubs for virtual functions as follows, which makes it thru.
/// @brief  The abstract Settings struct
struct Settings {
    /// Saves to persistance
    virtual void saveToPersistance() {}
    /// Loads from persistance
    virtual void loadFromPersistance() {}

    /// Marshall all values to make sure we are in range
    virtual void _marshallValues() {}

    /// @brief Update settings from the [args] and store to the persistance storage.
    /// Note that the order of the arguments is of great importance, shuffling them 
    /// results in unexpected behaviour.
    /// @param args The list of settings
    /// @param size The number of settings
    virtual void storeSettings(float args[], size_t size) {}

    /// @brief Dump data
    /// @param message The message to display in the dump header
    virtual void dump(const char * message) {}


    /// @brief Load settings from the persistan storage
    inline void loadSettings() {
        // Load settings
        loadFromPersistance();
    }

    /// @brief Sends the config as a Json SDLTP thru BLE
    virtual void bleSendJson() {}
};

Btw, I did not have to:

instantiate Settings for a dummy instance;
add a destructor (nor a constructor).

The linker's happy and so do I :-)

You have to add virtual destructor if you are going to destroy objects though pointer to base. For example, let's say there is class ExtraSettings: public Settings. Now Settings* ptr = new ExtraSettings; delete ptr; and std::unique_ptr<Settings> = std::make_unique<ExtraSettings>(); are both Undefined Behaviour.
